# Foregrounding a modeless dialog after it's been backgrounded or minimized (MFC)

Tags: c++, mfc

I have some code which creates a modeless dialog:

```
m_ReminderDialog = new CReminderDialog();
m_ReminderDialog->Create(CReminderDialog::IDD, GetDesktopWindow());
    m_ReminderDialog->SetForegroundWindow();
```

Using a dialog template with this style:

```
STYLE DS_SETFONT | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME
EXSTYLE WS_EX_APPWINDOW | WS_EX_NOACTIVATE
```

This works; the dialog window is foregrounded (or flashed).

However, if the dialog window is minimized or put into the background,

```
m_ReminderDialog->ShowWindow(SW_SHOWNORMAL);
m_ReminderDialog->SetForegroundWindow();
```

doesn't work to foreground it, unless the main window has been minimized or disabled.

Why, and how to fix it?

Comment: You sure want here the DesktopWnd as ParentWnd for the dialog. Usually we use this for parent.

Comment: A modeless dialog still needs to be an [owned window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#owned-windows) of your program. Once you do that you'll see that all the broken foreground manipulation code is no longer necessary

Comment: @IInspectable It wouldn't work for the modeless dialog to be an owned window.  From that link, 
"An owned window is hidden when its owner is minimized."
Normally, the main window is minimized.  The reminder dialog needs to show up anyway.

Comment: In that case you want an unowned window, likely with its own button in the task bar. Either way, the brittle foreground activation dance is not needed.

Comment: @IInspectable  I would also like the reminder dialog to be foregrounded when the main window IS visible.  
It gets foregrounded when the reminder dialog is initially created.  But why not, after the reminder dialog has been minimized or put into the background?  
Maybe the WS_EX_NOACTIVATE style is causing the problem?  I could  use two different reminder dialog templates, one for when it's initially inactive and one for when it isn't.  I was trying to avoid that, but maybe it's necessary.

Comment: You don't need different dialogs. It's not the dialog that determines whether it is owned or not. It's the call to `Create` that establishes that relationship. `WS_EX_NOACTIVATE` is certainly an awkward style to use. Maybe the author tried to do [something else](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160912-00/?p=94295) but didn't know how to. Regardless, this all sounds like you're fighting the system rather than working with it.

Comment: @IInspectable Giving the reminder dialog the input focus is an option in the program, that's why I used WS_EX_NOACTIVATE. That's in case "reminders don't get input focus" is chosen. 
How to foreground the reminder after it's been minimized or backgrounded?